# Video Conference In HTML app

Tags: html

I have an HTML based application i want to add video conference any idea please. I want exact functionality like Skype. I have checked Skype API but it does not support video in HTMl. Any idea how i can implement in java script of Java.

Answer (score 1):

You will probably have to work with [node.js](http://nodejs.org/) for setting up a bidirectional client-server-communication with [WebSockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) ([some examples](http://html5labs.interoperabilitybridges.com/prototypes/websockets/websockets/info)). If you haven't heard of it, you can think of node.js as *serverside JavaScript*.

You will also need (something like) the [Media Capture API](http://html5labs.interoperabilitybridges.com/prototypes/media-capture-api/media-capture-api/info) to capture video and audio devices.

Try googling some of these keywords and you will find tons of examples how to work with them.

Good luck!